# Symfony 6.1 ChoiceType displays wrong values and choices

Tags: php, symfony

I have a question, I've got a form and, here is my code of form:

```
$builder
  ->add('type', ChoiceType::class, [
    'label' => 'app.security.type',
    'choices' => UserDictionary::POSSIBLE_CHOICES,
    'choice_label' => function (string $choice, string $key, string $value): string {
        return sprintf('app.choices.%s', $value);
    },
  ])
```

And here is my array:

```
public const POSSIBLE_CHOICES = [
    'choice1' => 'value1',
    'choice2' => 'value2',
    'choice3' => 'value3'
];
```

I've obfuscated real values because they aren't important here.

Expected result is to have select tag with options:

```
value1 => app.choices.choice1,
value2 => app.choices.choice2,
value3 => app.choices.choice3,
```

But what i get is:

```
choice1 => app.choices.choice1,
choice2 => app.choices.choice2,
choice3 => app.choices.choice3,
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: since you probably obfuscated stuff. Are you aware, that `ChoiceType` takes the choices in the form `label => value` (i.e. it will be turned into `<option="value">label</option>`)? This is at least what I stumbled over, the first time I used ChoiceType. And since what you're seeing is pretty confusing, could just be this misunderstanding, idk.

Comment: @Jakumi but here problem is that symfony for some reason ignores values and returns just choices, which are concatenated with translations. I used this method before, I mean function on 'choice_label' and it worked good, but now I have no idea what happen :D